Configuring nginx and passenger with rbenv for a rails app
On my ubuntu server, I switched the ruby versioning strategy from using rvm to rbenv.  When I restart the nginx server, I get this error:

Bundler was unable to find one of the gems defined in the Gemfile

However, this exception is a bit misleading because another message says that a possible issue is:

The application may be run under the wrong Ruby interpreter. It is currently being run under /usr/bin/ruby2.7.

So I'm sure the issue is that the incorrect ruby interpreter is being referenced by passenger because I am actually running ruby version 3.2.4 with rbenv.  How do I fix this?

First you have to find where your desired ruby interpreter is. In linux: the easiest way to find that out is to run which ruby.
> which ruby
> /home/<SomeUserOnYourServer>/.rbenv/shims/ruby

Then go to the server block of your nginx configuration and specify that path above (the path to your desired ruby interpreter) for the passenger_ruby directive:
passenger_ruby /home/<SomeUserOnYourServer>/.rbenv/shims/ruby;

Restart your nginx server and see if it worked.

/etc/nginx/conf.d is a directory not a file so maybe you meant /etc/nginx/conf.d/mod-http-passenger.conf. Either way this is an auto generated file and does not need to be modified at all. Passenger recommends you change the passenger_ruby in the server block of the nginx configuration files for the site (/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp) or the default (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default). Docs
